# Destroying connection that could not be successfully matched : Error in jboss while connecting with Database

Tags: database, web-applications, datasource, jboss7.x, struts-1

Modified: I am using Jboss 7 server and oracle 10g for my web Application but when I starting the server application working properly but after 2 or 3 hours it is becoming slow.

I guessed like.
1. connection is not happening between database and jboss server properly so that it is not fetching data, so cause of this it becoming slow.

Datasource information in my standalone-full.xml file in jboss server is below:

```
  <datasources>
                <datasource jndi-name="java:/TTKConnectionDataSource" pool-name="TTKConnectionDataSourcePool" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="false">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.1.0.112:1521:vidaltest</connection-url>
                    <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver-class>
                    <driver>oracle</driver>
                    <transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</transaction-isolation>
                    <pool>
                        <min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
                        <max-pool-size>150</max-pool-size>
                        <prefill>true</prefill>
                        <use-strict-min>true</use-strict-min>
                        <flush-strategy>FailingConnectionOnly</flush-strategy>
                    </pool>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>appln</user-name>
                        <password>appln</password>
                    </security>
                    <validation>
                        <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleValidConnectionChecker"/>
                        <validate-on-match>true</validate-on-match>
                        <background-validation-millis>300000</background-validation-millis>
                        <stale-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleStaleConnectionChecker"/>
                        <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleExceptionSorter"/>
                    </validation>
                    <timeout>
                        <idle-timeout-minutes>10</idle-timeout-minutes>
                    </timeout>
                </datasource>
```

And error what I am getting during slow down of server :

```
11:31:04,689 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (http-web-10) IJ000612: Destroying connection that could not be successfully matched: org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener@323ff8fa[state=DESTROYED managed connection=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnection@62b2c9f connection handles=0 lastUse=1494391408674 trackByTx=false pool=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool@547ac048 pool internal context=SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool@46e5e24c[pool=TTKConnectionDataSourcePool] xaResource=LocalXAResourceImpl@1e6c0ff1[connectionListener=323ff8fa connectionManager=488aa6d1 warned=false currentXid=null] txSync=null]
11:37:09,075 INFO  [com.ttk.action.claims.TTKListener] (http-web-20) Session is created sessionCreated
11:37:09,078 ERROR [org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction] (http-web-20) Request[/LoginAction] does not contain handler parameter named 'mode'.  This may be caused by whitespace in the label text.
11:46:35,964 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory] (http-web-10) Destroying connection that is not valid, due to the following exception: oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@5b8b1ccb: java.sql.SQLException: pingDatabase failed status=-1
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleValidConnectionChecker.isValidConnection(OracleValidConnectionChecker.java:74) [ironjacamar-jdbc-1.0.12.Final.jar:1.0.12.Final]

05: Connection error occured: org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener@38b370[state=NORMAL managed connection=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnection@a8c7e2d connection handles=0 lastUse=1494390662156 trackByTx=false pool=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool@547ac048 pool internal context=SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool@46e5e24c[pool=TTKConnectionDataSourcePool] xaResource=LocalXAResourceImpl@dafc1c4[connectionListener=38b370 connectionManager=488aa6d1 warned=false currentXid=null] txSync=null]: java.sql.SQLException: pingDatabase failed status=-1
```

when I am restarting server than connection is fine up to 2 or 3 hours maximum after that server again becoming slowdown ,Please suggest me what are the possibilities to overcome on this issue.

Thanks in advance.

sorry for disturbance, but again I am facing this problem actually what is happening ? when my server become slowdown then it's not allowing me to login its keep on buffering because its not connecting with my database as i think or may be its not getting connection object. and after some time of buffering its giving warning message what i mentioned above "Destroying connection that could not be successfully matched" . than after that if i will try to login the application than its taking time to get login or last option i need to restart my server that is not that much preferable ever.

Answer (score 2):

The WARN messages are not unusual when something outside JBoss closes a connection.

That warning indicates that JBoss got the Oracle JDBC driver to ping the database to ensure that the connection still worked, and it reported that it didn't, so JBoss destroyed the connection. JBoss would then create a new one and give that to the application, so it should in theory not cause any actual problems.

Method "org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleValidConnectionChecker.isValidConnection()" throws this exception. Method isValidConnection() internally calls OracleConnection's pingDatabase() [1] method. It the database is closed it returns -1, refer [2]. This issue is a known issue with Oracle driver which is seen when their are issues with network or database and is not related to JBoss

This is a known type of error indicating some problem with your Oracle database or occasionally with the network.

I would ask you to check the network connectivity is stable between the JBoss node and Database.

[1] https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleConnection.html#pingDatabase__

[2] https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleConnection.html#DATABASE_CLOSED

Comment: Anup can you please suggest me how I can check network connectivity is stable or not between the JBoss node and Database.

Comment: - Test the network with the usual means like ping, telnet, ssh... connection tests.
- Check if your DNS name resolution is working properly; use an IP address instead of a hostname when in doubt.
- Test if connections to the Oracle database are working using the Oracle tnsping utility or with SQL*plus.
Note: requires a native Oracle client install.

Comment: checked everything proper but today when i tried in morning same issue again i faced ,my web application  not allow to login itself

Comment: The "Destroying connection" warnings are seen when connections are removed from the pool, in your case, as it was from a pingDatabase call, it would have been during connection validation. This is normal as you have validation in place. JBoss should attempt to create a new connection for the application if it finds the connection in the pool invalid.

Comment: if the connections in the pool are closed by the database, perhaps from a timeout on the database side, they will remain in the pool until an application tries to get one. At this time the validation will find it invalid and destroy the connection, logging the warning

Comment: I am destroying session without closing connection and result set object. it can be also a problem. destroying session by calling session.invalidate() method

Comment: sorry for disturbance, but again I am facing this problem actually what is happening ?

Comment: sorry for disturbance, but again I am facing this problem actually what is happening ? when my server become slowdown then it's not allowing me to login its keep on buffering because its not connecting with my database a s i think or may be its not getting connection object. and after some time of buffering its giving warning message what i mentioned above "Destroying connection that could not be successfully matched" . than after that if i will try to login the application than its taking time to get login or last option i need to restart my server that is not that much preferable ever.

Comment: Found a way to solve this? Notice something similar in one of my applications. But then I am thinking this could be due to high network packet loss or something.